# How to download XML file from URL using C# or VB.Net Script Task in SSIS

Tags: xml, vb.net, reporting-services, ssis, script-task

I am trying to download an XMLFile output from the SSRS Report. I am having issues in Script Task of C# and VB.Net

I am getting below issue

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

```
Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://exmaple.com/XMLFileForDownLoad"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object


WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open("GET", myURL, False)
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
Dim oStream As Object = Nothing
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1

    oStream.Write(WinHttpReq.ResponseBody)
    oStream.SaveToFile("C:\temp\file.xml")
    oStream.Close
End If
```

I want to download file in the Local

Comment: It appears that you cut off the beginning of the Error Message. Was there an error code (there usually is)?

Comment: Error is complete.  It is inside the window  DTS Script task: run Time Error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: This exception is thrown when there is an error while executing the script. You must add breakpoints and debug the script code the specify the error source.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve using VBScript following below and it worked as desired.

[Execute and Download SSRS Report as XML using SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3475/execute-a-sql-server-reporting-services-report-from-integration-services-package/)